# Recent brew upgrade breaking vim

Tags: macos, vim, python, homebrew

This question is closely related to [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/1096438/brew-upgrade-broke-vim-on-os-x-dyld-library-not-loaded) where I got a very similar error message when launching vim after doing a brew upgrade:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/python/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/Python
  Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/vim
  Reason: image not found
Abort trap: 6
```

The solution was to reinstall ruby and vim, however in my case it was probably caused by downgrading Python 3.7 back to 3.6 (3.7 ended up breaking a lot of libraries that I am using due to incompatibility,) and reinstalling Python3.6 and Vim didn't help.

I am not sure why Vim is looking for Python 3.7, which I don't even have on my machine. The only versions I have are 3.6.5, 2.7, and system Python.

Both vim and python were installed from brew.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by reinstalling Python 3.7 with brew, and Python 3.6.5 with pyenv. This way they don't conflict with each other and I get to decide which Python version I want to use.